# How to set a TypoError in Node.Js and Discord.Js for a bot to join a voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Good evening,
I'm developing a music Bot Discord in Javascript with Node.Js and I have this problem:

Here it's the "play" command, but I run into this with all commands that ask to join a voice channel.

[typoerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDcM6.png)

Voici le code :

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'play',
  aliases: ['p'],
  category: 'Music',
  utilisation: '{prefix}play [name/URL]',

  execute(client, message, args) {
      if (!message.member.channel) return message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.error} - T'es pas dans le channel vocal !`);
      
      if (!args[0]) return message.channels.send(`${client.emotes.error} - Indique le nom de la musique!`);

      client.player.play(message, args.join(" "), { firstResult: true });
  },
};
```

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageManager, Message, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

const Discord = require('discord.js');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();



const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => { 
    console.log('Troubadour is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'play'){
        client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) does not have a `channel` property. You might have meant to use [`GuildMember.voice`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice)[`.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel):

```js
if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.error} - T'es pas dans le channel vocal !`);
```

Note: You may have to check that the command is coming from a guild, using something like:

- ```js
  if (!message.member?.voice.channel)
  ```
- ```js
  if (message.member && !message.member.voice.channel)
  ```

Comment: Well, actually it's the same error but with "voice"

Comment: See updated answer. You may have to check that the message is coming from a guild channel